# How pssh do the ssh activities without password

Tags: linux, ssh, security, password, parallel-ssh

the follwing pssh command do a parallel as date

```
pssh -i -H "master01 master02 master03 worker01 worker02"  -l root -x '-q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o GSSAPIAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=publickey -o PubkeyAuthentication=yes' date | grep -v "^\["
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
Fri Jul 12 12:37:35 UTC 2019
```

but we notice that the password for the machines not defined 
so how pssh do the ssh activities without password ?

Comment: Can you provided more information on how your SSH server is configured?

Comment: some of the servers have the public keys and some no , the servers that no have public keys return to pssh the right value  , so pssh can works with servers that public keys was sent and servers without public keys

Comment: Do you know if server is configured as keyless ssh?

Answer (score 0):

Your pcommand sets the ssh option `PubkeyAuthentication=yes`. This means it will use a key pair to log in instead of passwords. The private key is on the machine where you run this. Check whether the private key is encrypted and compare the printed public key with the file `/root/.ssh/authorized_keys` on the remote machines.

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -y -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```

- If ssh-keygen doesn't prompt you for a passphrase, then your private key is not encrypted. Rather learn how to use `ssh-agent` and encrypt your private key. Otherwise anyone with that file can login as root on your machines!

```bash
$ ssh-keygen -p -f $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
```