# How to launch the password in pssh command

Tags: shell-script, ssh, rhel, ssh-agent

when we want to use pssh in order to get in parallel the command output from remote machine we can do ( for example )

```
pssh -H  presto01 -l root -A -i "hostname"
Warning: do not enter your password if anyone else has superuser
privileges or access to your account.
Password:
[1] 11:55:56 [SUCCESS] presto01
presto01
```

but how to do it without entering the password , so the password will be lunch automatically?

Comment: Isn't this the same as https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/529818/117549 ?

Comment: no , this is about entering password

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we can use sshpass

```
sshpass -p customer pssh  -H presto01 -l root -A -i "hostname"
```

Comment: Interesting thing that it is still necessary to tell pssh to ask for a password so that sshpass actually can pass a password - Intuitively I'd expect it to do it automatically. Thx for sharing your knowledge +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

You can set up a [passphrase based authentication between the server and the client](https://www.golinuxhub.com/2012/08/rsa-and-dsa-authentication.html).

Next source/export the ssh-agent on the server

```
# eval `ssh-agent` ssh-add /root/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Here I assume that my private key is stored under above provided path /root/.ssh

Once you give the password the ssh-agent will perform a passwordless connection.
Now you can do pssh without using "-A" option

More examples on PSSH (check Use SSHD options with PSSH)

https://www.golinuxcloud.com/pssh-commands-parallel-ssh-linux-examples/

In my setup I have configured passwordless configuration, and I prefer pssh using below additional sshd option

```
StrictHostKeyChecking=no
GSSAPIAuthentication=no
PreferredAuthentications=publickey
PubkeyAuthentication=yes
```